# increasing the size of root partition and reducing the size of home

Tags: partition, gparted

I want to take 20G from my `/home` and put it in my `/`. I logged into live installation drive and launched `gparted`.

The partitions look like this:

[image]

`sda4` is root, `sda5` is boot and `sda6` my home partition.

If I click on `sda6` and resize it from left to right I will get a warning that `moving partition might cause your operating system to fail to boot` and after that partitions look like this:
[image]

Now there is `sda5`(my boot partition) in the way and the only way is to move it to the right of my unallocated space like this:

[image]

Now I can merge unallocated space with root:

[image]

**If I click apply will l`gparted` be able to generate new `fstab` or do I have to do it manually?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for `gparted` to generate a new `/etc/fstab` (it never does this anyway). You are not creating any new partitions or changing UUIDs, so you should be good to go.

That being said, that warning is posted for a reason: PLEASE have a system backup in case `gparted` crashes.

Comment: also had to re-install grub since the beginning of the boot partition is moved